# How to draw a positively skewed "normal" distribution

Tags: tikz-graphdrawing

[image: Positively Skewed "Normal" Distribution]

How to draw a positively skewed "normal" distribution, as shown above? I understand it's not even normal.

Comment: You could warp the x axis (parametric).  x=sqrt(t+a) might do,.  x=log{t) (log normal) has historical value.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thx, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried $3*1/exp(((sqrt(\x+5)-3)^2)/2)$, but shows almost a flat curve. Domain is 0:6. Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Simply multiply the error function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution)

Comment: Oops, that should have been `x=exp(t)` and, or `y=exp(-t*t)` etc.  BTW, never use `t^2` instead of `t*t` when computing.